# what does "static int function(...) __acquires(..) __releases(...){" mean?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I recently got a snippet of code in Linux kernel:

```
static int
fb_mmap(struct file *file, struct vm_area_struct * vma)
__acquires(&info->lock)
__releases(&info->lock)
{
...
}
```

What confused me is the two __functions following `static int fb_mmap()` right before `"{"`,

`a).`What is the purpose of the two __funtions?

`b).`Why in that position?

`c).`Why do they have the prefix `"__"`?

`d).`Are there other examples similar to this?

Comment: They are most likely macros, so search the header files for their definitions.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I don't recall in C syntax that you can put ANYTHING in that position.

Comment: It's most likely that the macros expand to the GCC extension `__attribute__` which can indeed be placed in that position.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Not everything ending with a pair of parenthesis is a function (call). In this case they are parameterized macro expansions. The macros are defined as

```
#define __acquires(x)  __attribute__((context(x,0,1)))
#define __releases(x)  __attribute__((context(x,1,0)))
```

in file `include/linux/compiler.h` in the kernel build tree.

The purpose of those macros expanding into attribute definitions is to annotate the function symbols with information about which *locking structures* the function will acquire (i.e. lock) and release (i.e. unlock). The purpose of those in particular is debugging locking mechanisms (the Linux kernel contains some code that allows it to detect potential deadlock situations and report on this).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse

`__attribute__` is a keyword specific to the GCC compiler, that allows to assign, well, attributes to a given symbol
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#Function-Attributes

Since macros are expanded at the text level, before the compiler is even looking at it, the result for your particular snippet, that the actual compilers sees would be

```
static int
fb_mmap(struct file *file, struct vm_area_struct * vma)
__attribute__((context(&info->lock,0,1)))
__attribute__((context(&info->lock,1,0)))
{
…
}
```

Those macros start with a double underscore `__`  to indicate, that they are part of the compiler environment. All identifiers starting with one or two underscores are reserved for the compiler environment implementation. In the case of the Linux kernel, because Linux is a operating system kernel that does not (because it simply is not availible) use the standard library, it's natural for it, do define it's own compiler environment definitions, private to it. Hence the two underscores to indicate, that this is compiler environment/implementation specific stuff.

Answer (score 1):

They're probably macros defined with `#define`. You should look for the definition of such macros and see what they expand to. They might expand to some `pragma` giving *hints* to the compiler; they might expand to nothing giving *hints* to the developers or some analysis tool. The meaning might vary

Comment: You can put a macro in that position?? I don't recall in C syntax that you can put ANYTHING in that position. Is there anything else I can put in that pisition?

Comment: You can put macros wherever you want. When the pre-processor parses the source file it, more or less, does a *Find and Replace* of the macro with its content. It might expand to nothing, which is obviously fine; it might expand to some pragma, which might still be fine depending on the compiler

Answer (score 1):

The `__attribute__` these macros evaluate to are compiler-specific features.  `man gcc` explains some of the uses.

The prefix `__` typically is used to avoid name clashes; double underscore as prefix and postfix mark an identifier as being used by the compiler itself.

More on gcc attributes can be found [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Attribute-Syntax.html).

More on the kernel use of these can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse).

Answer (score 0):

Those are macro's defined as

```
# define __acquires(x)  __attribute__((context(x,0,1)))
# define __releases(x)  __attribute__((context(x,1,0)))
```

in Linux/include/linux/compiler.h

Comment: Thank you, what confused me the most is their position. I don't recall you can put a thing in that position.