# What is something like function call before the braces in function definition?

Tags: c, linux

I am reading Linux kernel source code and found a syntax I've never seen before.

For example, this code:
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v5.13-rc6/fs/io_uring.c#L9980-L9985

```c
static int __io_uring_register(struct io_ring_ctx *ctx, unsigned opcode,
                               void __user *arg, unsigned nr_args)
    __releases(ctx->uring_lock)
    __acquires(ctx->uring_lock)
{
    // [more code here...]
}
```

Here we see `__releases(ctx->uring_lock)` and `__acquires(ctx->uring_lock)` outside the braces.

- What do these parts do?
- What are they called (name) in C?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21018778/what-does-static-int-function-acquires-releases-mean.

Comment: Yeah, that answers my question. Thanks. Marked as duplicate now.